# Lotus Domino Agent Manager JVM Memory

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm running a scheduled agent which interrogates a particular directory on the the file system to find image files and change their dimensions if they're above a certain file size.

I'm using the Java image library called ImgScalr: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

The problem I'm having is that on some images the process falls over with a java.lang.OutOfMemory error. The images which it falls over on are relatively large, usually between 5MB and 6MB.

The server it's running on has 8GB of RAM which I thought would be ok.

My question is does the Agent Manager JVM utilise the same memory settings as the HTTP task i.e. HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize?

I've increased that setting to 1792MB but that doesn't seem to have an impact when the image reduction agent runs. Note, increasing the config to anything above that figure makes the HTTP JVM throw the following error on startup: **HTTP JVM: JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc24(2): Failed to instantiate heap; 2G requested)**

If the Agent Manager doesn't use the same setting as the HTTP JVM then does it have it's own setting we can change to increase the available memory in order to stop getting the OutOfMemory errors?

Comment: No, it does not share the HTTP JVM's setting. The equivalent setting for the Agent Manager is `JavaMaxHeapSize`, but you should not need to set it that high. The Domino server requires a lot of shared memory, and setting JavaMaxHeapSize too high dedicates so much address space in the AMGR task to  robs all the other tasks of the address space that they need in order to set up their shared memory.      8 GB of RAM is of little use to you if you are running 32 bit Domino, as the max for every task is 2 GB, and the shared memory for all tasks also must come out of that 2 GB.

Comment: Thanks Richard, increasing that certainly helped and it seems to only fall over on much bigger images now which is much more manageable...

Comment: How much did you increase it to? 128 MB really should be enough for almost anything.  The default is 64 MB. If you are raising it much higher, than you are risking starving other parts of the server for memory. Does your code do anything with the Notes/Domino classes for databases and documents? If so, have you checked for missing recycle() calls?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is does the Agent Manager JVM utilise the same memory
>   settings as the HTTP task i.e. HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize?

Is the Agent Manager running within the same Java process as the `HTTP` task?  If so, then the most likely answer is yes.  But you don't have to rely on guesswork, you can just connect to the Java process using [JConsole](http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/) or [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) (both are free and come with the JDK) - and find out for yourself.  By doing so, you should even see a spike in the telemetry data at the point in which your process fails.

> Note, increasing the config to anything above that figure makes the
>   HTTP JVM throw the following error on startup: HTTP JVM: JVMJ9VM015W
>   Initialization error for library j9gc24(2): Failed to instantiate
>   heap; 2G requested)

You are probably using a `32-bit` Java runtime, which will have much less addressable memory.  Try either running with `-d64` (which assumes you have both 32 and 64 bit versions available), or downloading and replacing your runtime with the 64-bit version of Java.  Or read the [FAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296452) on IBM's page, specifically the part that says:

> Question: Does Domino run as a 64-bit application? Answer: Domino
>   8.0.1 and 8.0.2 runs as a 64-bit application on the following 64-bit operating systems (OS

Comment: I don't think it's quite as simple as installing a different version of Java in this case. The JVM being used is tightly integrated into the Domino server so I suspect trying to change it will cause issues for the server. Java -version in the relevant directory returns the following:

Comment: java version "1.6.0"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3260sr4ifix-20090820_01(SR4+IZ54545+IZ55984+148736+IZ54462+IZ58406))
    IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Server 2008 x86-32 jvmwi3260
    sr4ifx-20090729_39787 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
    J9VM - 20090729_039787_lHdSMr
    JIT  - r9_20090213_2028
    GC   - 20090729_AA)
    JCL  - 20090803_02

Comment: The portion that reads: x86-32 confirms that you are not using a 64-bit JVM.  What sort of 'tight integration' do you suspect exists?  Is there a version you could download that does include the 64-bit JVM?

Comment: Hi Amir, no I hadn't read that so thanks for the link. It's a relatively new customer site so we've had no input on the server version until now. I'll get the next upgrade done using the 64bit version and see if that also improves things. Thanks for your help.